# Add UIImage to CCSprite?

Tags: ios, image, api, cocos2d-iphone

I do not know if this is stupid or not but I have been scratching my head over this for about an hour or two now.

I am getting a `NSData` object from `NSUserDefaults` then converting it to a `UIImage`. Now how do I set of the image of my `CCSprite` to my UIImage?

`spriteWithFile` doesn't work here since it requires a `NSString`. I am looking for an API that has a parameter of a `UIImage`. Is this possible?

Any ideas?

**Edit1**: How is this?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData*)obj];
sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:image.CGImage key:@"mainSprite"];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one:

```
CCTexture2D *tex = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:uiImage] autorelease];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];
```

uiImage is a UIImage object.

Comment: I have to use CCSprite :/ And in the first example you are doing it the normal way of using a NSString. I need to pass a UIImage in instead of a NSString!

Comment: My edited code is above please check that.

Comment: initWithImage is deprecated. Would you mind showing the use of the newer API were supposed to use? And besides the picture, the physical appearance of the sprite isn't any different because I use CCTexture2D right?

Comment: check edit1 in my original post

Comment: initWithImage: method doesn't exist in the current version of cocos2d

Comment: use  [puzzleSprite1 setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache]addImage:imgName]]

Comment: CCTexture2D *tex = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:uiImage] autorelease]; causing termination of program showing [CCTexture2D initWithImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14378580 in cocos2d-iphone v2.1.

Answer (score 1):

This method is working perfectly for me ...

```
 -(CCSprite*)spriteFromDiskFileName:(NSString*)fileName
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *directoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ;
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];

        UIImage *spriteImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        if (spriteImage) {
            printf("\nUIImage created from disk image \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nUIImage creation failed from disk image \n");
        }

        CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithCGImage:spriteImage.CGImage resolutionType:kCCResolutionUnknown];
        return [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
    }
```